# GWT UiConstructor with optional parameters

Tags: gwt, uibinder

We have a custom widget with 4 parameters. One of these parameters is optional.
If we use the widget in UiBinder and omit the optional field an error is thrown.

For example

```
MyWidget(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
  ...
}
```

If in the UiBinder file I write

```
...
<b:MyWidget arg1="sdfsd" arg2="fsdgds" arg3="ertlkj">
...
```

If I write

```
...
<b:MyWidget arg1="sdfsd" arg2="fsdgds">
...
```

Then the following error occurs:

```
[ERROR] <MyWidget arg1="sdfsd" arg2="fsdgds"> missing required attribute(s): arg3:     <b:MyWidget arg1="sdfsd" arg2="fsdgds">
```

Is there any way to define optional arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better or worse, no - this is how UiBinder is designed. You can only designate one `@UiConstructor`, and UiBinder will always use that constructor.

If possible, instead of making them constructor arguments, make them setters. The `setArg3()` method will be optionally called if the `arg3` attribute is present, rather than trying to switch between constructors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any optional parameters in your widget - all of them are required. You can do:

```
MyWidget(String arg1, String arg2) {
  ...
}

public void setArg3(String arg3) {
    this.arg3 = arg3;
}
```

Or:

```
MyWidget() {
}
public void setArg1(String arg1) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
}
public void setArg2(String arg2) {
    this.arg2 = arg2;
}
public void setArg3(String arg3) {
    this.arg3 = arg3;
}
```

Then both of your Ui:Binder declarations should work.

Comment: I'll test it with `var-args` If possible.