# Can I use default constructor and @UiConstructor simultaneously?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

If I create a GWT widget with two constructors: a default constructor and another one annotated with @UiConstructor - is it possible to use both in ui.xml templates? Or does the presence of the @UiConstructor annotation mean that there's absolutely no way to use any of the other constructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer is a no: if any of the constructors is marked with @UiConstructor, then you must write the ui.xml template exactly according to that single constructor. Test widget class:

```
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiConstructor;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;

public class UiConstructorTest extends Label {

    public UiConstructorTest() {
        setText("default constructor");
    }

    @UiConstructor
    public UiConstructorTest(String text) {
        setText(text);
    }
}
```

Omitting the arguments results in a UiBinder error such as this (instead of invoking the default constructor):

```
00:00:15,072  [ERROR] <my:UiConstructorTest ui:field='testLabel'> missing required attribute(s): text: <my:UiConstructorTest ui:field='testLabel'> (:14)
```

Of course, the widget can still have other constructors. The limitation only means that you won't be able to use any of them in ui.xml templates (except the annotated one). The default constructor is not an exception to this rule.

I guess if it was possible to use both the annotated and the default constructors, it would lead to confusing situations. For example, if we have a widget with a default constructor, a UiConstructor with a String text parameter, and a setText(String text) setter, this template declaration would be ambigious:

```
<my:UiConstructorTest ui:field='testLabel' text="isThisAConstructorParameterOrASetterParameter?">
```

Should UiBinder instantiate with the UiConstructor marked constructor? Or should it use the default constructor, then call the setter?

Comment: Your "confusing" case is easy to deal with: there just needs to be a rule saying that `@UiConstructor` takes precedence. It'd be more of an issue for cases like a constructor taking 2 arguments and only one is given as an attribute, so you'd have to fallback to using the default constructor and setter; also what would happen if the constructor parameter and the setter have different types and the attribute's value can only be parsed for one of them and not the other? (and don't forget the interactions with other parameters/attributes: that case could happen twice, with conflicting resolutions)

Comment: Actually, the "default constructor or `@UiConstructor`" rule would not be much different than an "any number of `@UiConstructor`-annotated constructors" rule.

Answer (score 1):

the spec of `@UiConstructor` (which can be found [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiConstructor.html)) says that
[`@UiConstructor`] `Marks a constructor that may be used as an alternative to a widget's zero args construtor in a UiBinder template. The parameter names of the constructor may be filled as xml element attribute values.`

So, by the spec it seems that you can have a zero-args constructor, and/or an annotated constructor whose arguments can be specified via xml. Apart from that, you can't have more than one annotated constructor, since UiBinder should choose the right one in that case. For any other constructor, I think it will be ignored.

Comment: Yout cannot have more than one constructors annotated with @UiConstructor, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24209508/209452 The rest of your answer is just plain guesswork.

Comment: Well, You asked if it was possible to have (and use in UiBinder) 2 constructors, the default one and one annotated with `@UiConstructor`. Apart from trying to be informative by linking the javadoc for reference, my answer just says that you can, but you can't have more than one annotated constructor (giving an hint on the reason of that limitation), and that any other constructor will be ignored by UiBinder. If my wording made you think that I was just guessing, I'm sorry.